# How to detect only one specified class instead of all classes in tensorflow object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I trained my dataset with six classes and it works fine in detection different classes. Is it possible to modify object detector script to detect only one specified class instead of all six classes? Or I must retrain my dataset for one class again from scratch? Thanks a lot for any recommendation.
Here is my drawing part of object detector script:

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
image,
np.squeeze(boxes),
np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
np.squeeze(scores),
category_index,
use_normalized_coordinates=True,
line_thickness=1,
agnostic_mode=False,
groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
skip_scores=False,
skip_labels=False,
min_score_thresh=0.80)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change the code, you're going to get probabilities for all the classes. Ofc, you can select highest one among em. Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks Mark. Could You please explain which part of the code should be change? I trained me dataset for 6 classes but i now need to detect one of them. i.e. drawing bounded box for one class instead of 6 classes.

Comment: you mention anchor boxes for `n` number of boxes, when you wanna detect n boxes. So part of code where you mention those many classes should be changed. In my opinion you should retrain your model. As those extra classes are just going to create confusion for detecting that one classes. If you're reluctant to re-train it try it without seeing and take next move based on accuracy.

Comment: Is there any way that detection script does not draw rectangle box for other 5 classes at all? I means I would like that script only draw boxes for one classes and skips 5 other classes. thanks again Mark.

Comment: I told ye, remove those extra anchor boxes. Try it?

Comment: How can I remove the  extra boxes?  you mean I should increase the threshold rate to remove poor probabilities?

Comment: that's one way of going about it, but that depends on how you code. For example in using some algorithm like YOLO, we create a matrix in which top most element is if there is any element in a grid or not and rest of the element determine the classes and location of coordinate. So as many classes as I wanna detect I'll have those many classes followed by variable of coordinates.

Comment: I use faster rcnn inception v2 model. Now I am going to search for detection_classes location in my code. I know it is  better that retrain my set again but i want to involve  myself with this code first a bit. Maybe i can modify detection_classes tensor. Thanks Mark for your kind recommend.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution to this problem, but you could try making a copy of the label_map.pbtxt-file (one to alter and one for safe-keeping) and delete all labels but the one you are interested in, in one of them.

Then you can lower the min_score_thresh to maybe 0.1 or something (or not modify this parameter at all), and only detect the one label you kept in the label_map.pbtxt-file.

If you are using the Object detection API from GitHub, the mscoco_label_map.pbtxt-file can be found in models-master/research/object_detection/data/ (remember to open it with a text-editor)

Answer (score 0):

Before you call the visualization function add the following code -

---

```
objectOfInterest = 1  # Interested object class number as per label file 
box = np.asarray(boxes)
cls = np.asarray(classes).astype(np.int32)
scr = np.asarray(scores)
bl = (cls == objectOfInterest) 
classes = np.extract(boolar,cls)
scores = np.extract(boolar,scr)
boxes = np.extract(boolar,box)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The code suggested below by Suman was almost perfect, but the "boxes" array needs to be a 4 position tuple (box coordinates). To select a specific class, selecting the matching box coordinate tuple is needed. So I've added some lines before the code suggested by Suman. Check the code below:

```
objectOfInterest = 1  # Interested object class number as per label file
box = np.asarray(boxes)
cls = np.asarray(classes).astype(np.int32)
scr = np.asarray(scores)
    
boxes = [] 
for in range(1, len(cls)):    
    if cls[i] == objectOfInterest:
           boxes.append(box[i])
boxes = np.array(boxes)
     
bl = (cls == objectOfInterest)
classes = np.extract(boolar,cls)
scores = np.extract(boolar,scr)
```